# Source for the minhag of 'gebrokts'

Tags: minhag, passover, sources-mekorot, stringency-chumrah, gebrochts

There is a not-uncommon minhag, primarily in chassidic circles called 'gebrokts' where matza is not allowed to come into contact with water during Pesach.  What is the earliest source for this custom and it's meaning?